# jquery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide

I'm a jQuery novice, I have the following jQuery written to show a div when a specific link on a map is shown:

```
<div id="locationmap">
    <a class="linkhide" id="link1" href="#">Occupier 1</a>
    <a class="linkhide" id="link2" href="#">Occupier 2</a>
    <a class="linkhide" id="link3" href="#">Occupier 3</a>
</div>  
<div id="mapdetail">
    <div class="hideme" id="local1" style="display:none;">
        <p>Some content one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hideme" id="local2" style="display:none;">
        <p>Some content two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hideme" id="local3" style="display:none;">
        <p>Some content three</p>
    </div>    
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $("#link1").mouseover(function() { $("#local1").fadeIn(500); });
    $("#link2").mouseover(function() { $("#local2").fadeIn(500); });
    $("#link3").mouseover(function() { $("#local3").fadeIn(500); });

    $(".linkhide").mouseout(function() { $(".hideme").css('display','none'); });
//]]>
</script>
```

However, as you can see the .fadeIn(500) is being repeated for each link. How would I make this a variable once and call it for each line? This would save me repeating the same piece of code 30 times or so for each link.

I have a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/karlgoldstraw/4NRY7/

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I didn't know there'd be so many different ways to achieve my result. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function mouseOver(localId) {
    return function() { $("#local" + localId).fadeIn(500); }
}

 $("#link1").mouseover(mouseOver(1));
```

Comment: Perfect! This works exactly how i want it to. Cuts down my code and now I only have to change the 500 in one place if i need a slower fade in speed. Thanks!!

Comment: This still requires you to attach the event listener separately for each `.linkhide` though. Please see my answer below that is dynamic and only requires calling `jQuery.mouseover()` once for all (not each) `.linkhide` elements.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a data-attribute to make the connection between the links and the div simpler,,,

```
<a data-id="2"...

$('a.linkhide').mouseover(function() {
  var el = '#local' + $(this).data('id');
  $(el).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacement for your current script.

This allows you to use a single dynamic function, and a single `jQuery.mouseover()` call, for all `.linkhide` elements, to avoid the duplication of code that still results from @MikeThomsen's answer.

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

  $( ".linkhide" ).mouseover( function ( event ) {

    var item_id = this.id.match( /([0-9]+)$/ )[1];

    $( "#local" + item_id ).fadeIn( 500 );

  } );


  $( ".linkhide" ).mouseout( function () {

      $( ".hideme" ).css( 'display', 'none' );

  } );

} );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way that doesn't involve changing the HTML.  As you can probably tell, changing the id of the link could make this much more efficient.

```
$(".linkhide").mouseover(function() {
    var linkDivMap = { 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3, 'four' : 4 };
    var contentBox =$(this).attr('id').replace('link','');
    $("#content" + linkDivMap[contentBox] ).fadeIn(500);
});

$(".linkhide").mouseout(function() { $(".hideme").css('display','none'); });
```

Comment: Yes, in their JSfiddle the OP has different `id`s for the `.linkhide`s. But even if you were going to code around that, you'd be better off using a map rather than a switch as in your code. E.g.: `{ 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3, 'four' : 4 }`

Answer (score 1):

Because i don't see it yet i thought i would add my answer here. Though i realize that the above answers are perfectly viable my solution lets the link tell the function what the content to show is called. By adding a javascript function that will inspect the hash value of the link you can use that as a selector to do your fadein's. This would also give the benefit of degrading better as the hash link would still put the user on the correct content in the event javascript is disabled.

JavaScript

```
var fade = function(){
    var contentSelector = this.hash;
    $(contentSelector).fadeIn(500);
};
```

Then to declare the mouseovers:

```
$("#linkone").mouseover(fade);
$("#linktwo").mouseover(fade);
$("#linkthree").mouseover(fade);
$("#linkfour").mouseover(fade);
```

Or you could even do it like this:

```
$(".linkhide").mouseover(fade);
```

Then on the HTML

```
<a class="linkhide" id="linkone" href="#content1">Link 1</a>
<a class="linkhide" id="linktwo" href="#content2">Link 2</a>
<a class="linkhide" id="linkthree" href="#content3">Link 3</a>
<a class="linkhide" id="linkfour" href="#content4">Link 4</a>
```

etc...

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4NRY7/11/

Comment: Hi, this also works really well - I appreciate the answer and have marked it up. I copied the code from your Jsfiddle link to try it. Great stuff